Unity, Как в коде получить название музыки и исполнителя?
Много искал, но так и не нашёл ответа на это, мне нужно именно в коде узнать название музыки, НЕ ИМЯ ФАЙЛА, А ИМЕННО НАЗВАНИЕ МУЗЫКИ, которое находится в описание этого файла вместе с названием альбома и исполнителя, и достать эту информацию, желательно всю
source.clip.name мне не подходит, он обращается к имени файла, не знаю как ещё это объяснить(
пожалуйста, напишите кодом и поясните как получить эту информацию
заранее спасибо❤️‍

Это зависит от формата музыки, но в среднем гyглить куда-то в такую сторону https://forum.unity.com/threads/getting-the-image-of-an-audio-file.756401/

Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO! как задать хороший вопрос => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

я так полагаю стоит использовать библиотеку TagLibSharp для этого? или есть ещё другие варианты?

Вопрос мягко говоря не на тему Unity3D. Довольно странно в видеоигровойм движке ожидать функционал чтения метаданных из ресурсных файлов. Более того, есть вероятность, что после билда этих данных там не будет, ибо ресурсы проекта подвергаются компрессии. И не с каждой библиотекой можно сбилдить проект и не под каждую платформу.
